# Measurability and integrability of set and function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

My textbook said:

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, let $G$ be an open set, and let $|\cdot|_e$ denote outer measure.

1. if $\exists{}G$ s.t. $E\subset{}G$ and $|G-E|_e\lt\varepsilon$ for an any given $\varepsilon$, then $E$ is measurable.
2. if $\{\mathbf{x}\in{}E: f(\mathbf{x})\gt{}a\}$, for every finite $a$, is measurable, then $f$ is measurable.
3. if $\int_E f$ exists and is finite, then $f$ is integrable on $E$.

---

Q1) My book common wrote that "~~~ said to be measurable if ~~~." Are converses of them correct? that is,

1. $\exists{}G$ s.t. $E\subset{}G$ and $|G-E|_e\lt\varepsilon$ for an any given $\varepsilon$, if $E$ is measurable.
2. $\{\mathbf{x}\in{}E: f(\mathbf{x})\gt{}a\}$, for every finite $a$, is measurable, if $f$ is measurable.
3. $\int_E f$ exists and is finite, if $f$ is integrable on $E$.

---

Q2) is "for every finite $a$" equal to writing "for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$"?

---

Q3) Is the following theorem correct?

1. If $f$ is measurable, then $f$ is integrable over $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.
2. If $f$ is integrable over $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, then $f$ is measurable.

Comment: There must be some condition on set $G$. If not then you can take $G=E$ and *any* set $E$ would be measurable.

Comment: @drhab Thank you. My textbook said $G$ is commonly an open set and $F$ is commonly a closed set.

Comment: Q1) *Definitions* are usually given as "if"-statements. It is correct to read them as "iff"-statements. So the converses are correct (if we are dealing indeed with definitions). Also a yes on Q2). On Q3)1 No, $f$ can be measurable and at the same time not integrable (depends on measure). Q3)2. Yes, only measurable functions can be integrable.

Comment: @drhab Thank you very much. This is an answer to which I exactly wanted.